# Where can I find the rule on position of ‘nicht’ in clauses after ‘daß’ using compound past tense?

Tags: relative-clause, position

I am trying to apologise for delay in response:

> Es tut mir leid daß ich nicht früher antworten könnte

or

> Es tut mir leid daß ich früher antworten nicht könnte

or

> Es tut mir leid daß ich früher antworten könnte nicht

Answer (score 1):

First a couple nitpicks: German usually prefers to put a comma between clauses even if none is required in English, so it would be customary to put a comma between *leid* and *daß* in your examples. Also, the current spelling rules say to use *dass* instead of *daß*. It's a recent change though, so if you're learning from an older textbook you may be used to the other spelling.

The general rule of thumb is that *nicht* is placed before what is actually being negated. I don't think it usually matters for the logical meaning, but it does make a difference in emphasis. In this case, "answering earlier" is what you want to negate, so the *nicht* goes in front of *früher antworten*. I'm a learner myself so I don't have a native speaker's ear for these things, but the second and third sentences don't sound right to me. When verbs are at the end of a subordinate clause like this, I think they prefer to have that area to themselves, so no putting *nicht* between verbs and no putting *nicht* after the final verb.

Comment: Yes, the third sentence is plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

RDBury already mentioned it in [his answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69842/1487):

- *»daß«* is wrong since 1996. Correct is *»dass«*

Next error: The subordinating conjunction *»dass«* initiates a subordinating clause that needs to be separated from the main clause by a comma.

Another thing that is wrong is *»könnte«.* *»Könnte«* (with umlauts) is *Konjunktiv II* (in this case: *conditional* in English), this is a mood or mode. Moods in German grammar are: *Indikativ, Konjunktiv I, Konjunktiv II* and *Imperativ.* English has other moods, but they are similar. This is *Konjunktiv II:*

> Ich **könnte** dich töten wenn ich wollte, aber ich will nicht.
> I **could** kill you if I wanted to, but I don't want to.

What you need is *»konnte«* (without umlauts), this is the Präteritum form of *»können«.* Präteritum is a German tense, similar to past tense in English:

> Vor 40 Jahren **konnte** Erich noch stundenlang tanzen.
> 40 years ago, Erich **could** dance for hours.

Another error in your sentences is the missing full stop (period) at the end.

---

So, after having corrected these 4 errors, we have these 3 choices:

> a. Es tut mir leid, dass ich **nicht** früher antworten konnte.
> b. Es tut mir leid, dass ich früher antworten **nicht** konnte.
> c. Es tut mir leid, dass ich früher antworten konnte **nicht.**

Only one of them is correct, and this is option *a:*

> correct: Es tut mir leid, dass ich **nicht** früher antworten konnte.
> <sup>I'm sorry that I could **not** respond earlier.</sup>

The negation comes before the item it negates. So these three possibilities are correct:

> 1. Es tut mir leid, dass **nicht ich** früher antworten konnte.
>    I am sorry that it was **not me** who could respond earlier.
> 2. Es tut mir leid, dass ich **nicht früher** antworten konnte.
>    I'm sorry that I could respond **not earlier.**
> 3. Es tut mir leid, dass ich früher **nicht antworten** konnte.
>    I'm sorry that I could **not respond** earlier.

I know that in English grammar the translation of #2 is not perfect, but I have chosen this unusual form, to show what is going on in the German sentence.

In #1 the negation negates the person. So, it was another person who responded in the past, but a respond was given early.

#2 and #3 have in common, that the respond was given late, so they are very similar. They are so similar, that you use the same translation in English for both of them, but there still is a subtile difference in German:

In #2 the adverb *»früher«* is negated. This means, that I could respond, but I couldn't do it at the desired time. In #3 the verb *»antworten«* is negated. This means, that I could have done something else earlier, but responding was not an option at that time. The effect is the same: An early respond was impossible, but the reasons are different.

---

So, why are your options *b* and *c* wrong?

> b. Es tut mir leid, dass ich früher antworten **nicht konnte.**

Here you are negating the modal verb *»konnte«* (a form of *»können«*), but this makes no sense.

> c. Es tut mir leid, dass ich früher antworten konnte **nicht.**

Having the negation at the very end of a sentence is only possible if there is no subordinate clause. In this case the whole action is negated:

> Ich verkaufe das Auto **nicht.**
> I do**n't** sell the car.

Only short sentences without any subclauses can have the negation at the end. If there are more components in a sentence, the negation moves inside the sentence:

> Ich verkaufe das Auto **nicht heute** an Tante Monika.
> <sup>I'm selling the car to aunt Monika **not today.**</sup>
> Ich verkaufe das Auto heute **nicht an Tante Monika.**
> <sup>I'm selling the car today **not to aunt Monika.**</sup>

(Usual translation for both versions: *I'm not selling the car to Aunt Monika today.*)

Comment: I would translate your sentence #3 with: "I'm sorry that earlier I could not respond." It puts a stress on apologizing for what happened earlier, i.e. not being able to respond.